# How to resize input accessory view

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

Working with show hide iphone keyboard with image button, that on the top of the keyboard.

```
    [kbdImage setFrame:CGRectMake(290, 0, 30, 30)];                                                             
    [accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(290, 0, 320, 30)];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyBoard:)];
     gestureRecogniser.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

     [accessoryView addSubview:kbdImage];
     [accessoryView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecogniser];


     for (UIView* v in searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
           ((UITextField*)v).inputAccessoryView = accessoryView ;
        }
     }
```

This works for hide keyboard. But the remaining area in the input view also touchable. How to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are adding tap gestures to the whole `AccessoryView` so the whole View will be responding to tap gestures, instead of it adding tap gestures to only that image button.

```
    kbdImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [kbdImage addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecogniser];
```

Comment: I tried that before. It doesn't work for me. Even tap is not working when set the GestureRecognizer for the imageview.

Comment: you have set userinteraction enabled on imageview?